# Regex replacing between brackets that contain the same type of bracket in between

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I am trying to replace the following string

```
\section{Welcome to $\mathbb{R}^n$}
Some content
```

with

```
<h1>Welcome to $\mathbb{R}^n$</h1>
Some content
```

Obviously, the problem is that I have opening `{` and `}` between the curly brackets themselves. I have tried to use something like

```
strOutput = strOutput.replace(/\\section\*\s*\{([^}]*)\}/g, "<h1>$1</h1>");
```

in JavaScript, but with no luck. How do I go on approaching this?

Comment: Not just `/^\\section\*\s*\{(.*)\}$/g`? Questions stated in terms of a single example are ambiguous 84% of the time. It's best to state questions in words, precisely, and then use one or more examples for illustration. Here you need to state the *rule* for determining the part of the string that is to be extracted.

Comment: Update your question to expand on the problem instead of commenting on answers. Add your examples to the question. Also, It's lame to change the question / problem after an answer was accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the OP's use case of nested and un-nested curly braces one needs a regex which explicitly targets and captures the content in between two braces (opening/closing) which also contains a pair of opening/closing braces ... [`/\{(?<nested>[^{}]+\{[^{}]+\}[^{}]+)\}/g`](https://regex101.com/r/z4hZUt/1/) ...

```js
const sample = String.raw`\section{Welcome to $\mathbb{R}^n$} \textbf{Other text} \textbf{Other text}  \textbf{Other text} \textbf{Other text} \section{Welcome to $\mathbb{R}^n$}  \textbf{Other text}\section{Welcome to $\mathbb{R}^n$} \textbf{Other text} \textbf{Other text}  \textbf{Other text} \textbf{Other text} \section{Welcome to $\mathbb{R}^n$}  \textbf{Other text}`;

// see ... [https://regex101.com/r/z4hZUt/1/]
const regXNested = /\{(?<nested>[^{}]+\{[^{}]+\}[^{}]+)\}/g;

console.log(
  sample
    .replace(regXNested, (match, nested) => `<h1>${ nested }</h1>`)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```js
let str = String.raw`\section{Welcome to $\mathbb{R}^n$}`

let result = `<h1>${str.match(/(?<={).*(?=})/)}</h1>`

console.log(result)
```

Comment: using non-capturing groups is pretty good too.

Comment: As soon as some other text is added, the code does not work. For instance, `\section{Welcome to $\mathbb{R}^n$} \textbf{Other text}` gets replaced by `<h1>Welcome to $\mathbb{R}^n$} \textbf{Other text</h1>`, whereas I need it to be `<h1>Welcome to $\mathbb{R}^n$</h1> \textbf{Other text}`.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```js
let str = String.raw`\section{Welcome to $\mathbb{R}^n$}`
let m = str.replace(/\\section\s*\{(.*)}$/g, "$1")
let result = `<h1>${m}</h1>`

console.log(result)
```

The problem with your expression was `\*`, which means a literal asterisks, but otherwise you nearly had it!

Comment: As soon as some other text is added, the code does not work. For instance, `\section{Welcome to $\mathbb{R}^n$} \textbf{Other text}` gets replaced by `<h1>Welcome to $\mathbb{R}^n$} \textbf{Other text</h1>`, whereas I need it to be `<h1>Welcome to $\mathbb{R}^n$</h1> \textbf{Other text}`.